# Oracle SQL performance low due to a lot of data

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, database-performance

One of our table has ~500000 items and because of that queries like this (with joins) works very slow:

```
SELECT something
FROM TABLE_WITH_A_LOT_OF_DATA t
LEFT JOIN table1 t1 ON t1.id=t.t1_id
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.id=t1.t2_id
WHERE <some complicated clause with subqueries and so on>;
```

What's more, business logic of our application is very complex and `WHERE` clauses are complicated. So the question is: `what are the ways to increase performance of sql queries which search for data through tables with a lot of data?` We aren't db specialists and we read that we can use partitions and/or materialized views. Are there any other options? Which one is the best?

Comment: There is not best solution in general. Its all case to case basis. We cannot assume anything to give up a solution for your scenario. If you need a concrete answer, then you should provide exact SQL query, Plan, Sample result set, Time values, Optimizer mode, etc

Comment: Estimate data distribution for every column in your tables that appears in `where` clause. Choose columns which are used often and contains different values, and then create indexes on that columns. It is a first thing you should do. For example: you have date column with dates of events. Dates is distributed evenly in period for some years, and every time you selecting rows for one day. In this case index on this field can improve your performance. But, in any case, it is very hard to give any advices without detailed information about your system.

Answer (score 1):

There is not one good answer to a question like this. If there were a single magic secret to good database performance then everyone would probably use it. Also, it's worth noting that the table you mentioned is not particularly large, I have worked on databases with tables several orders of magnitude larger, which is still well within the scales that can be handled by a well designed database. (The point of saying this is that you shouldn't conclude that there is just too much data to be able to get good performance from a relational database).

The most obvious avenue to look down is whether you have the indexes that you need. First of all think about whether the queries that are performing slowly are intended to return a small number of records. If you are targeting a small proportion of the overall table then building indexes on columns that you frequently filter by can be very effective. Think of this like using indexes in a book, if you have to search the whole book for each word you are looking up (like full table scans) then it will be slow. On the other hand if you plan to return a large proportion of the table e.g. >~15% then indexes may not be a good solution (at some point it becomes more efficient to just look at every record rather than going back and forth to the index all of the time.

Also, don't go crazy with indexes, adding them does add some overhead to inserts / updates.

This is just one consideration, but is probably the easiest potential gain if it is appropriate for your scenario. This is obviously a very broad question, so I will not attempt to cover all of the factors that could improve performance.